# Opening sentence in cover letter?

Tags: meaning, grammar

I am currently writing my cover letter for an application.

In the opening sentence I want to put emphasis on the most important fact about my profile: That I am a statistician and that this is my passion. I am applying in the area of financial statistics. I thought about using the classical "I am writing to apply", but instead somehow a punchline, something like:

```
Statistics and solving quantitatitve problems is my passion. I studied .....
```

I am not sure about this sentence, first is this a good idea? Second is the "is" correct? Or is an "are" necessary?

Comment: The first sentence seems OK to me, except for spelling 'quantitative' as 'quantitatitve'. Whether to use *is* or *are* depends on whether you conceive of "Statistics and solving quantitative problems" as a single area of interest or two separate areas. I think both variants are fine. If it was up to me, I'd use *is*.  -- Incidentally, you closed this question after just FOUR MINUTES. Why?

Comment: The first question is subjective, open-ended, and off-topic. The second is a duplicate. Would you say "My brother and my sister is my family?"

Comment: OK... I see that someone else closed the question.